# How to use 'geth' to find a smart contract in the ropsten testnet

Tags: go-ethereum

I try to connect with web3.php to a smart contract, published in the ropsten test network via metamask. I used the following web3.php library: (https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php). To create an rpc server, I used ethereum go and run the following commands:

```
geth --testnet removedb
geth --testnet --rpc
```

Which should make a test node, connected to the ropsten test net. Now I run the following code in php, but the result i get back is always "error", which means, it does not find the smart contract. Has anyone an idea, why it does not find the contract in the ropsten test network? I think somehow I'm not connected to it with ethereum-go. I also published the smart contract on a local testrpc, where it works fine.

```
<?php

require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Web3\Web3;
use Web3\Contract;
use Web3\Providers\HttpProvider;
use Web3\RequestManagers\HttpRequestManager;

$abi='[
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "value",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getValue",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    }
]';

$web3 = new Web3(new HttpProvider(new HttpRequestManager('http://localhost:8545')));

$contract = new Contract($web3->provider, $abi);
$contractAddress='0x3ed9bd43bb425c0acc202421f54e8de72b8d91f9';
$functionName='getValue';

$contract->at($contractAddress)->call($functionName, function ($err, $result) use ($contract) {
    if ($err !== null) {
        echo "error";
        throw $err;
    }

    if ($result) {
        echo $result;
    }
});
```

When I start my node, i get the following command output:
[image]

Edit: eth.getBlock('latest')
[image]

Comment: Is it synced up with the network? if you use `eth.syncing` and get a false but `eth.getBlock('latest')` differs from the actual tip of the chain, or the fist comands returns something other than `false`, then the chain is not synced up. As you have launched the node without a console you should attach to it to do this (`geth attach http:localhost:8545`)

Comment: Hi Hari, eth.syncing gives me back false, so this should be alright. Can I somehow see if the contract is actually in the network? How can I see uf eth.getBlock('latest') is the actual tip of the chain?

Comment: I think i found the problem, when I run "geth --testnet --rpc", it won't begin to sync. So what do I need to do to sync the testnet with go-ethereum? Only "geth --rpc" will start to sync, but on the main net, that's not what I want for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, its a fairly common problem. Default bootnodes tend to be overloaded, so adding others should help you. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/rfikki/42d7ecd55225fe867855ef2f4cb004d0) should be enough